# Why is my IIS configuration file not changing when IIS options are changed?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

Edit: IIS version is 7.5, Windows 7 Ultimate

I'm very confused as to what is going on here. No matter what changes I make in IIS (deleting application pools, adding new pools, adding new websites etc.) I do not see a *single* change in the `applicationHost.config` file.

The files located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config` and `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config` are not being altered at all, in fact the names for the application pools and websites in those configuration files aren't *even close* to the ones in the actual IIS manager.

Is there some 3rd location where the REAL configuration file is?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you working with? What files are listed in the file-list drop-down in IIS Manager if you open the Configuration Management page?

Comment: This list appears normally... too many things to list here.

Comment: Do you have IIS Express installed? It's possible that you're configuring IIS Express instead of "normal" IIS.

Comment: I guess this website doesn't work properly so I have to comment twice rather than editing my previous comment: I added the IIS/Windows versions to the original post.

Comment: I doubt that would be possible, the configuration file for IIS Express is not located in either of those locations. I have also not interacted with IIS Express in any way on this installation of WIndows.

Comment: Try running Sysinternals ProcMon and seeing what files are modified when you make changes: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: @Dai The only place I see a config file that actually reflects the current state of IIS is located in `C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000055` - Which is *completely* insane because that directory effectively changes after every change you make...

Comment: Lol, this is a rather cute observation: I can remove `applicationHost.config` from `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` and IIS produces an error. When I add that file back in, it reads from that file **once**, and then never looks at it or uses it again... I can edit that file till I'm blue in the face or edit settings in IIS itself and that file will *never* change again... it does however think it needs to read from that file to initialize. Pretty shocking behaviour to be honest. @Dai

Comment: You revealed some magic that only happens on your machine. Thus, unless you provide more information such as screen shots (IIS Manager, configuration file and so on) and video, nobody can dig further for you.

Comment: None of that would have helped at all. Anyway, it was an issue of multiple text editors being simultaneously incapable of updating that file *or* seeing changes made to that file. There something very strange with the permissions on that install of Win7.